# Call function again only after it finish executing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that gets called every time the enter key is pressed. I need to make it so that the function will NOT be called if you press the enter key again, IF and when the function has not finish executing yet. Only when the function has finished executing, will it be called again if you press the enter key again. How would I do this in jQuery, or JavaScript?

```
onKeyDown = 'if(event.keyCode==13) someFunction()'

function someFunction() {

//some codes
//some setTimeouts

}
```

Comment: http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Comment: What you mention can´t happen. Javascript is single treaded.  You can only have "some code" executed "disordered" when you are waiting for an ajax callback or a timeout. But even on that cases the code is completely executed before javascript attends to a new event. (sorry about my english)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply set a Boolean when done and check it before executing the function.

```js
onKeyDown = 'if(event.keyCode==13) { if (!finished){someFunction();}'
var finished = false;
function someFunction() {
   finished = false

   //some codes
   //some setTimeouts

  finished = true;
}
```

Though, as Luis points out, Javascript is single threaded and so you shouldn't be running into the problems you describe unless I am not understanding your problem fully.

Comment: Shouldn't var finished = false; be inside of the someFunction()?

Comment: Nope, it's meant as a global variable.  As soon as the function is finished, the global variable will be set to true and `someFunction` will no longer be called.  You will need to have the global `finished` variable reset to false if you want future enters to trigger.

Comment: @Scott you either mean to invert the true at the end so someFunction(){ finished = true //some code //some settimeouts finished = false;}